# How to programmatically drop a file on a Windows app?

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop

I'm looking to have a particular running instance of Visual Studio open a file. Is there a way I can fake a drag-drop operation via code from my app to Visual Studio? Same as if I were to drag a file from Explorer into VS.

I realize I could probably do this easier as an add-in or macro but I'm looking to make this work purely from a script.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sending a WM_DROPFILES message to the Visual Studio window.

Comment: Tried it, verified it's received with Spy++ but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hmmm, other people seem to have success with it.  I hooked up Winspector and watched Visual Studio's messages while I dropped files.  I never saw a WM_DROPFILES message.

Comment: I didn't put a lot of time into it yet. Just used this I found on the googles: http://forums.fanatic.net.nz/index.php?showtopic=18873 but haven't looked into what the problem is just yet.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, and the Forum mentioned above is offline apparently. Does anybody know how to actually perform a Drop operation to any Window that supports drag and drop?